# Can not print updatedAT column from Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.5

I have a table in postgres, and I want to get only the `updatedAt` column. If I print the table columns, the updatedAt exists:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import sys
import datetime

con = None

try:

    con = psycopg2.connect(database='db', user='dbuser', password='1111')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * from incidents')

    column_names = [row[0] for row in cur.description]

    print("Column names: %s\n" % column_names)


except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
    print('Error %s' % e)
    sys.exit(1)


finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
```

the result is

```
Column names: ['id', 'deviceId', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'city', 'area', 'address', 'state', 'postalCode', 'country', 'canceled', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'patientId']
```

But when I try to select all the rows from that table and get only the updatedAt info, it says that this column does not exist.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import sys
import datetime

con = None

try:

    con = psycopg2.connect(database='db', user='dbuser', password='1111')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT updatedAt from incidents')
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)


except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
    print('Error %s' % e)
    sys.exit(1)


finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
```

The error message is:

```
Error column "updatedat" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT updatedAt from incidents
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "incidents.updatedAt".
```

I also tried with `incidents.updatedAt`, but with no luck.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention that this table has been created from Node.js with Sequelize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres column names default to lower-case. Since that column name has an upper-case letter in it, it must be quoted in order to be referenced. The same would be true if the column had a space or a special character in it. This query should work:

```
SELECT "updatedAt" FROM incidents
```

Comment: hehe! awesome! works like a charm! Thank you very much!!